# New JHipster app with v5.0.1 with Easticsearch generates (HTTP code 500) server error

Tags: jhipster

Created new JHipster app with v5.0.1, all normal.

Imported JDL, all normal.

./mvnw, all normal

Yarn start, all normal

Attempt to start Docker container for Elasticsearch using:

```
docker-compose -f src/main/docker/elasticsearch.yml up -d
```

Get error:

> (HTTP code 500) server error - Cannot restart container
>   cd1b5c16ec1a7d80faf2dad7a92f68963b5023597c24279c4c0a5d7138083128:
>   driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint
>   docker_project-elasticsearch_1
>   (b806bc9fc7b37a03b47ec8b87d55f95e76a8f580567440cdc5ce140c7ace57a4):
>   Error starting userland proxy: mkdir
>   /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:9300:tcp:172.18.0.2:9300: input/output error

Suggestions?

Comment: Make sure you don't have anything using ports 9200/9300

Comment: negative...no conflict

Answer (score 1):

Possible fix?

Reference following, scroll to bottom:

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3277

I'm using Docker for Windows

Turn off Docker autostart

Or restart Docker

Appears to correct the problem.

Seems like this would be a common complaint. Anybody seen this?